# What does "associate" mean in a relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading [this](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/every-monomial-ideal-has-a-unique-inclusion-minimal-monomial-generating-set/) and it defines a $\sigma$ relation by "associates"

Comment: "Associate" isn't something about a relation, it is a name for a particular relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two elements $r$ and $s$ in a commutative ring are called "associate" if $r\mid s$ and $s\mid r$ (by transitivity of $\mid$, it follows that for all $t$, $r\mid t$ iff $s\mid t$).  Equivalently, $r$ and $s$ are associate if the ideals $(r)$ and $(s)$ are equal.

Comment: Ah or $a = ub$ for $a,b \in R$ in a ring with $u$ being a unit.

Comment: @hawk No, that is not equivalent unless you are working in an integral domain. The condition you mention does always imply the divisibility condition, though.